# Angular 6 dynamically apply CSS class to mat-cell

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I have material table in which depending on content of the cell I need to use specific CSS class.
[image]

I use the following css classes

```
.status-code{
    flex: 0 0 10% !important;
    width: 10% !important;
}

.status-code-succsess{
    flex: 0 0 10% !important;
    width: 10% !important;
    background: rgb(196,214,160);
    color: rgb(80,99,42);
}

.status-code-failed{
    flex: 0 0 10% !important;
    width: 10% !important;
    background: rgb(229,185,181);
    color: rgb(97,38,33);
}

.status-code-empty{
    flex: 0 0 10% !important;
    width: 10% !important;
    background: rgb(216,216,216);
}
```

Here's the html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Warehouse">
                <mat-header-cell class="status-code" *matHeaderCellDef> Warehouse </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="{{row.warehouse}} == 'Success' ? status-code-success : ({{row.warehouse}} == 'Failed' ? status-code-failed : status-code-empty)" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.warehouse}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="DPI">
                <mat-header-cell class="status-code" *matHeaderCellDef> DPI </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="{{row.dpi}} == 'Success' ? status-code-success : ({{row.dpi}} == 'Failed' ? status-code-failed : status-code-empty)" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.dpi}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

However, I have just one row of data with 'Success' in Warehouse cell, but it gives me style with pink background

[image]

Please help, what may be wrong?

Comment: Try using [ngClass] instead of class and also no need for brackets "{}" for writing row.warehouse.
You can write it as <mat-cell [ngClass]="row.warehouse...">

Comment: Thanks, but when I use this <mat-cell ng-class="row.warehouse == 'Success' ? status-code-success : (row.warehouse == 'Failed' ? status-code-failed : status-code-empty)" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.warehouse}} </mat-cell>                                     no style is applied at all ((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using `[ngClass]`.

You may have to make following changes while using `ngClass` :

*. Remove the interpolation `{}` against each variable
*. Include all `class names` in  `single quotes`.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Warehouse">
    <mat-header-cell class="status-code" *matHeaderCellDef> Warehouse </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell [ngClass]="row.warehouse == 'Success' ? 'status-code-success' : (row.warehouse == 'Failed' ? 'status-code-failed' : 'status-code-empty')"
         *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.warehouse}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="DPI">
    <mat-header-cell class="status-code" *matHeaderCellDef> DPI </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell [ngClass]="row.dpi == 'Success' ? 'status-code-success' : (row.dpi == 'Failed' ? 'status-code-failed' : 'status-code-empty')"
         *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.dpi}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Also you have a typo in class name.

Change `.status-code-succsess` as `.status-code-success`

```
.status-code-success{
    flex: 0 0 10% !important;
    width: 10% !important;
    background: rgb(196,214,160);
    color: rgb(80,99,42);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, there was really a typo. However nothing has changed.. It still works incorrectly. Pink background is everywhere

Comment: Try using `ngClass`. Remove the interpolation  and include all `class names` in  `single quotes`. Check updated answer

Comment: Yeah, with [ngClass] it works perfectly! Thank you very much

Comment: BTW, maybe you have an idea how to make this statuses with slightly rounded corners and with margin as on the 1-st picture? Changing style to               
 .status-code-success{
    flex: 0 0 10% !important;
    width: 10% !important;
    background: rgb(196,214,160);
    color: rgb(80,99,42);
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}    gives this margin to the rest of the cells which is not acceptable

Comment: Try  something like `border-radius: 20px` for that

Comment: I have implemented same solution but what if I want to move ngClass logic to ts file call it in html.